# How to check which is the current version of repository I'm working on in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I know I can use `hg tip` to check the newest verision of local repository. But I don't know which version I've checkout into and working on so I need to check it.  I tried to google it but didn't find the right command..

Comment: The Node ID (of *each* commit) represents the "version" for the commit. You can Pull from the remote repository (usually if changes are intended to be merged to) or just view the remote.

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
hg parents [-r REV] [FILE]

show the parents of the working directory or revision
```

You can run `hg help` to get the list of available commands.

It like to run `hg summary` which includes the parent:

```
$ hg summary --remote
parent: 1967:3ffa3a76de21 tip
 removed all source code
branch: new_one
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
remote: 1 or more incoming
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hg id` in order to detect active changeset of repository

```
>hg id -nibt
ad4dd1a9ba66 38 default tip
```

If changeset changed on update

```
>hg up -r 35
4 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Re-check id

```
>hg id -nibt
8a72023d18d0 35 default
```